# how to exclude fields from swagger grpc generated code

Tags: swagger, protocol-buffers, grpc

i'm trying to generate swagger `JSON` files using https://github.com/pseudomuto/protoc-gen-doc, I can't find a way to exclude some of the  APIs of the grpc service/fields inside the messages.

found the relevant styling in swagger, but can't seem to find a way to add it in the protobuf file http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/api-guidelines/swagger-coding-style.html#excluding-operations-from-the-sdks

```
service MyService {
    rpc ExternalApi (ExternalApiRequest) returns (ExternalApiResponse) {
        option (google.api.http) = {
            post: "/my/externalApi"
        };
    }
    rpc InternalApi (InternalApiRequest) returns (InternalApiResponse) {
        option (google.api.http) = {
            post: "/my/internalApi"
        };
    }

message ExternalApiResponse { 
string prefix = 1;
string id = 2;  // field to exclude
}

// message to exclude
message Header { }
```

is there a way to exclude actions / fields from the protocol buffer files?

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
string id = 2 [(grpc.gateway.protoc_gen_swagger.options.openapiv2_field).read_only = true];
```